# unable to understand the error in the code

Tags: java

```
public abstract class demo {
demo()
{

}
public void display(){System.out.println("this is from abstract class");}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    demo s=new demo(){
        public void display(){System.out.println("this is demo constructor");}
    }; 
    s.display();

}

}
```

In the above code i have tried to create an anonymous class that extends demo class and override display function but i am getting some error.The above code gives me an error in first line that "the type demo is already defined". I can't understand why it's giving this error.

Comment: Most likely you have another file in your project containing a class with the same name.

Comment: To add to what @yole mentioned: it works fine on Java 8u65 (oracle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code works fine. I guess the problem is that you already have a `demo` class defined somewhere in the same package (here the default one I guess, which is not a good practice).

Also, Java follows some conventions. For example, class names should begin with an uppercase. Here is a proper version of your code:

```
public abstract class Demo{

    public Demo(){}


    public void display(){
        System.out.println( "this is from abstract class" );
    }


    public static void main( String[] args ){
        Demo s = new Demo(){
            public void display(){
                System.out.println( "this is demo constructor" );
            }
        };
        s.display();
    }
}
```

As an aside, here the `abstract` keyword is not necessary. A regular class would have the same effect. `abstract` just prevents anyone to instantiate an object `Demo`...

Comment: the anonymous object that is created is referenced by the base class Demo. is it possible that i could reference by the anonymous variable? what would be its type?

Answer (score 0):

It's a name conflict; two classes with the same name in the same package. I would suggest to add a package name to remove the name conflict like this at the beginning of your file (before any import):

```
package com.test.demo
```